# Where can i get .setTestViewChartLocation since its not present inside ExtentReport 4.0.9

Tags: extentreports

I have added code in Eclipse for a Selenium project in `Reporting.java` class. I imported all the packages except `htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP)` It's throwing an error.. I cannot find this file inside extent reports 4.0.9. Where can I find this file?

```
htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
```

Comment: can you provide the error message? In ExtentReport V4, all the reporter classes are within this package - com.aventstack.extentreporters.reporter

Comment: see the usage/ config doc here - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/v3-html-reporter.html